# Call a pdf controller from another controller

Tags: symfony, pdf, controller

I have a controller document which render a PDF document.
From another document, i want to save this PDF
I try with :

```
/**
 * @Route("/test", name="test")
 * @Template()
 */
public function testAction()
{   
    $response = $this->forward('AcmeDemoBundle:Documents:documentUnique',
            array(
                'documentUniqueId'  => 2,
                'format_output' => 'pdf'
            )
        );
    $filename = ...;
    file_put_contents($filename, $response->getContent());
    return array();   
}
```

It save the pdf in $filename, BUT the browser also ask me to download the PDF ...
Is there a better solution ?

Comment: What do you have in the other controller for `documentUniqueAction`? You may return a response with something in header

Comment: Yes, it's ok if i don't send header in documentUniqueAction. thanks !